# Stihl fs 55 string trimmer not idling and blowing out white smoke

Tags: small-engine, smoke, trimmer

[image]

I just bought a string trimmer off of Facebook marketplace for 100. The guy that I bought it off of said that he put too much oil in it and that’s why it was blowing out smoke. I got it back home and realized that it does that regardless of the engine oil to fuel ratio. I want to see if I can fix it and hopefully use it for my small Lawncare business. I know that I should’ve been more thorough by looking over the equipment before buying it but this is the situation that I am in now. Could anyone give me some pointers on how I could resolve this problem. If anyone has any input on buying small engines off of Facebook, I’d also really appreciate it (things to check before buying).

Here’s the link to my video (you’re unable to see the smoke as the camera can’t capture it but it is blowing out light grey to white smoke from the exhaust)

https://youtube.com/shorts/Gv_NzxMFDg0?feature=share

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There is (to my knowledge) only two ways you are going to see smoke: too much oil in the mix; too much fuel period. I'm thinking the latter may be the problem, but don't know for sure. If there's no problem with it running, you could try just cycling through a couple of tanks of gas and see if the smoke tapers off. If that doesn't work, it'd have something to do with the carb and dumping too much fuel ... at least that's what my pea brain is suggesting to me.

Comment: In case you don't have this info, the gas:oil ratio for the FS55 is 50:1.  I assume you have the choke off.

Answer (score 7):

Too much oil tends to make blue smoke, not white.

Use fuel that you've purchased within the past 30 days. Seriously, do this before anything else. Stabilizer or not, some 2-strokes simply won't run unless the fuel is fresh.

I think the mixture is wrong.

Make sure the air cleaner is clean, not clogged. Make sure the plug is properly gapped and not fouled. Check or replace the fuel filter (if there is one), which may be in the fuel tank. With these basics covered, see if it runs right. If not, ---

Get the manual and adjust the carb according to procedure. If it still doesn't idle, try carb cleaner.

Finally, there's not much else to do but replace the carb, because if the ignition or intake / exhaust ports were messed up, it wouldn't start at all.